# Instagram API access token request fail

Tags: php, instagram, instagram-api

I seen answers for this in other posts but they are quite outdated and I know IG has updated their api since.

I followed their developer documentation but can not seem to make a request from my localhost.

```
$fields = array(
   'client_id'     => 'a2xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxed',
   'client_secret' => '3bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx8f',
   'grant_type'    => 'authorization_code',
   'redirect_uri'  => 'http://localhost:8000/',
   'code'          => 'code'
);

$url = 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch); 
print $result; //your token
```

The above code is how I am making my request but I get the following error.

```
{"code": 400, "error_type": "OAuthException", "error_message": "Matching code was not found or was already used."}
```

I have disabled implicit oAuth, the app set up is pretty basic, with all the settings going to my personal site for the time being as the app is in sandbox mode anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, I just had to logout of my Instagram account each time I wanted to request a new token.

Answer (score 0):

`redirect_uri` should be pointing to a public URL address, not `localhost`.

Comment: `http://localhost/` is a real URL, but it's not public. I allowed myself to edit your answer a little bit.